# Is it safe to use and update global variables in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables

I have a node server for loading certain scripts that can be written by anyone. I understand that when I fire up my Node server, modules load for the first time in the global scope. When one requests a page, it gets loaded by the "start server" callback; and I can use all the already loaded modules per request. But I haven't encountered a script where global variables get changed during request time and affects every single other instance in the process (maybe there is).

My question is, how safe is it, in terms of server crashing, to alter the global data? Also, suppose that that I have written a proper locking mechanism that will "pause" the server for all instances for a very short amount of time until the proper data is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node.js is single threaded. So it's impossible for two separate requests to alter a global variable simultaneously. So in theory, it's safe.

However, if you're doing stuff like keep user A's data temporarily in a variable and then when user A later submits another request use that variable be aware that user B may make a request in between potentially altering user A's data.

For such cases keeping global values in arrays or objects is one way of separating user data. Another strategy is to use a closure which is a common practice in callback-intensive or event/promise oriented libraries such as socket.io.

When it comes to multithreading or multiprocessing, message passing style API like node's built-in cluster module has the same guarantees of not clobbering globals since each process have its own global. There are several multithreading modules that's implemented similarly - one node instance per thread. However, shared memory style APIs can't make such guarantees since each thread is now a real OS thread which may preempt each other and clobber each others memory. So if you ever decide to try out one of the multithreading modules, be aware of this issue.

It is possible to implement fake shared memory using message passing though - sort of like how we do it with ajax or socket.io. So I'd personally avoid shared memory style multithreading unless I really, really need to cooperatively work on a very large dataset that would bog down message passing architectures.

Then again, remember, the web is a giant message passing architecture with the messages being HTML and XML and json. So message passing scales to Google size.

Comment: About user data part, the user A tries to store a global data. Whoever opens the request first appends the data to the global array. Then when user B opens it, he can use the global data on its own. I guess I clarified the unclear parts.

Comment: I need to read more about multithreading too. Thank you for the information!