# Cached asynchronous Node.js objects, avoiding callback hell

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, q

I've got an Express app that relies on a database that stores a JSON object to be used as the app's main configuration object. I'd like to cache this object so I don't have to keep going to the database to look it up. However, I'd also like a way to invalidate this cached object if a new configuration object is inserted into the database, and have my app pick up the new object without a restart. On top of that, I'd like to do all of this without digging too deep into callbacks

At the outset, this was an example of the code (this is contrived, so don't worry about the DB design or its premise -- it's not real). Assume users can be assigned a list of roles, that are stored in this "config" object:

```
// config.js
var config;

module.exports = function(cb) {
    if(config != null) {
    cb(config);
  } else {
    db.query('SELECT data FROM config', function(res) {
      config = JSON.parse(res.data);
      cb(config);
    })
  }
}

// users.js
var config = require('config');

var roles;
config(function(data) {
  roles = data['User Roles']; // Cache roles for the lifetime of the application, but doesn't allow for invalidation
});

module.exports = {
  get: function(id, cb) {
    db.query('SELECT name, roleIds FROM user WHERE id = $1', [id], function(res) {
      var userRoles = _.map(res.roleIds, function(roleId) {
        return roles[roleId];
      });

      cb({
        'name': res.name, 
        'roles': userRoles
      });
    });
  }
};
```

This code caches the user role definitions in `users.js` when the app is started, but there's no good way for me to invalidate the cache when I've updated the database with new config data. I've done a situation where I've instead wrapped the contents of the `get` function inside the call to `config()`, but I need to do this pattern numerous places in the code, and it just seems clunky to have to do that.

The ideal scenario, I think, would be something like this (using either callbacks or promises -- I'm fine with either):

```
// users.js
var config = require('config');

module.exports = {
  get: function(id, cb) {
    db.query('SELECT name, roleIds FROM user WHERE id = $1', [id], function(res) {
      var userRoles = _.map(res.roleIds, function(roleId) {
        return config('User Roles')[roleId]; // This call would either use the cached version or call out to the DB
      });

      cb({
        'name': res.name, 
        'roles': userRoles
      });
    });
  }
};
```

It seems like the real issue I'm grappling with is synchronousness. I want the function call to `config` (and perhaps its underlying call to the DB) to lazily load/cache the result, but still provide the value in-place whenever I need it, without overly nested callback structures/too much wrapping of code.

Hopefully this makes sense. If not, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: How do you get notified of the database being updated?

Comment: It's a callback. I'm using the pg module: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres

Comment: Is that already somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yeah, I omitted it for the purpose of brevity. I actually have a slim wrapper around that module's `connect`/`query` workflow that I expose simply as `db.query`. It's callback-driven right now, but I could just as easily create a promise and defer the query results. I'm just not sure I'd get many benefits in going that route.

Comment: Well, promises don't work for repeated updates; that's why I'm asking. What things do you expect to happen when the config is changed?

Comment: Aah, I see. I'd like the config cache to be invalidated, and its new value to be reflected by all of its consumers. In the first example, it's only evaluated once (when the module is loaded), and the other usage I've tried relies on me littering my code with mentions of `config(function(data) { ... })` that I'd ideally like to avoid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82145/discussion-between-monkey34-and-bergi).

Comment: At this point, I've tried to convert the code to use promises throughout, and it's just a complete mess. Everywhere I need to access the `config` object (which is a frequent case), I need a promise, and that means the caller of each of those functions needs to appropriately handle the promise(s) -- sometimes there are multiple promise-returning calls inside a single calling function, and I have to know which returns a promise and which doesn't, and handle them accordingly. Am I thinking too much about this? Should I just use a global `config` variable instead and call it a day?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are using `config` for, but it might be a good idea to pass it as parameter to each function (or part of a parameter, such as `req`). Then you can synchronously access it everywhere, and it's the callers responsibility to use the same config throughout one request.

Comment: I thought about doing that, too, but I have various model functions that my routes are calling, and I'd need to litter those function signatures with references to the `config` object as well; it would have been another headache to deal with. Globals seem to do the job well enough, since the value will be the same for the lifetime of any single request, but can be invalidated/updated at runtime to a new state from a `/config/update` endpoint (the desired outcome). I'm no fan of globals, but it seems to be a workable solution for my case.

Comment: "*the value will be the same for the lifetime of any single request*" - how do you know that?

Comment: That's the assumption I gleaned from reading about Node's single-threaded nature [(like this)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572166/is-it-safe-to-use-and-update-global-variables-in-nodejs). That for the duration of request A, nothing request B does can change request A's state. Even if Node can handle concurrent requests, as long as the value of the `config` object is the same *for any given request*, I'm OK with that. The worst that would happen is that user A sees slightly outdated data. Not ideal, but for this use case, acceptable. Let me know if that assumption is wrong, though!

Comment: No, because you're most likely doing asynchronous things when handling each requests. And that means that two (or more) requests can be going on concurrently. You cannot trust asynchronous callbacks!

Comment: Gotcha. Sounds like I might be trapped, then, either passing around the `config` object on the `req` namespace, or burying myself in promises/callbacks.