# Is it safe to define my io as global.io

Tags: node.js, sockets

I am new to nodejs and socket. What I would like to know is how I should able to access my `io` variable in different controllers or files. Is it safe to declare my `io` variable as:

```
global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

so now my `io` is accessible in any of my controller?

I got this idea from this link:
https://blog.sylo.space/use-global-variable-for-socket-io/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use and update global variables in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572166/is-it-safe-to-use-and-update-global-variables-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

It can cause crashes if it overlaps with another variable, which could be hard to track/handle if your project is quite big and/or includes a lot of librariers, it also exists for the lifetime of the application thus taking up resources. And it is overall considered bad practice to use global variables.

You can check out a great article about global variables in node.js here - http://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/

EDIT: Since you mentioned safety, it is safe on theory, just not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, global variables are an indication of poor software design. A better approach would be containing all your IO code in a distinct class/module. Here's a short code piece to illustrate what I mean:

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
class myIO {
    construct(server) {
        this.io = socketIO.listen(server)
    }

    doStuff() {
        // do stuff with your io socket
    }
}

module.exports = myIO;
```

Now you need to provide an instance of myIO to your controllers, but I'm not sure what constitutes a controller in your case. And do you need to reconnect socket each time, or reuse same socket?

Either way you might want to look into Dependency Injection pattern OR use a Singleton:

```
module.exports = new myIO();
```

in this case require("myio") would always return same socket. Or if your framework has a registry, you could use that.

Comment: I do understant what you are telling, but one question how can i pass server   parameter to construct function from any file because server instant will be created in app.js. how can i pass it from different file

Comment: Export the io server in any module file (e.g. `module.exports = socketIO.listen(server)`) then require it later from your controller file, e.g. `const io = require('./my-io')`